# Custom 3D Rendering

Tags: java, 3d, zbuffer

So I've been prodding ever so diligently at the internet as of late and have come across some interesting games. The basic example is [Minecraft4k](https://mojang.com/notch/j4k/minecraft4k/). It was made for the Java4k contest a few years back, but what I am really interested in is how the rendering was done. There are a lot of games like this made every year, but I really can't find much on how the creators went about synthesizing 3D worlds, let alone with minimal code.

The basics that would have be implemented would be polygon filling, z-ordering, and some sort of "fog" in order to prevent too much landscape from being drawn (optional, really). I've read up on the Scan line filling algorithm and have a working example but I have no idea how to get any form of z-buffering working. So the question is, does anyone have any experience with this sort of custom 3D rendering work? If so, any tips/pointers/resources you can point me to?

I know this is a bit of a shallow and perhaps inadequate question, but I figured I would try on here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering) is a good start point (though it is bad for me to post a link) and explains about different techniques.

I developed a 3D software renderer for dots (the simplest 3D renderer ever ;)) and the z-buffering consists of sorting an array of rendered elements according to the Z coordinate, which in turns depend on the projection you are using, either orthographic, isometric, etc. (see [another Wikipedia article about projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_projection)). In the simplest projection, you simply ignore the Z coordinate when drawing object, but take it into account during rotations (as it has an impact on X and Y).